# How to check Audio Stream supported or Not?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, alarmmanager, android-audiomanager

Hi i am building a app which uses **STREAM_ALARM**. There are some devices which does not support **STREAM_ALARM** (i think). As a result of this, my app is not playing music in these devices.

[image: Samsung Glaxy Note 4] [image: ZTE]

In above images, both devices have different Audio Manager controls. left side device does not have **ALARM_STREAM** (i think) that's why it is not playing sound.

This is how i am initializing my media player with STREAM_ALARM.

```
alarmMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
alarmMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
alarmMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, uri);
alarmMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
alarmMediaPlayer.prepare();
alarmMediaPlayer.start();
```

> [AudioManager Constants](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#constants_1) i read its documentation but found nothing

The Device which have control of Alarm in its **AudioManager**, Playing sounds but left side device is not playing sound.

So My Question is how can i check my device have **ALARM_STREAM** in its audio manager or not?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can actually check it. Normally if you want to check a device feature you should use

```
if (this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.APPFEATURE){}
```

but Packagemanager does not feature ALARM_STREAM  so I think you can should try:

```
int stream_alarmvolume=AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM;
```

and catch the error it gives if the system doesn't has this feature I don't know wich error it will give because I could not test it out.
I'm also not sure if it gives an error at all but you should give it a try.

Comment: well i appreciate your response. but i test it. on debugging AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM returns a int value. And device doesn't log any error